# Django: Nested OuterRef not woking to access grandparent's ID

Tags: python, django, rest

Trying to access FeeAccount model's id using **OuterRef** in a **nested subquery**, but **not immediate parent**. Throwing:

`ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

```
first_unpaid_fee_schedule_instalment = Subquery(FeeScheduleInstalment.objects \
    .annotate(
        total_balance = Subquery(
            FeeInstalmentTransaction.objects.filter(
                account_id=OuterRef(OuterRef('id')), # not working: need grand-parent's id here  
                instalment__schedule=OuterRef('id'), #working: parent's id
            ) \
            .values('balance') \
            .annotate(total_balance=Sum('balance')) \
            .values('total_balance')
        )
    ) \
    .values('id')[:1]
)


fee_accounts_with_first_unpaid = FeeAccount.objects \
    .annotate(
        first_unpaid_schedule = first_unpaid_fee_schedule_instalment,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating django version to 3.1
Previously it was 2.5. Maybe a version bug.